# Can SRTP use internal members?

Tags: f#, inline

I know that the *implementation* of `inline` code can't use internal/private code. However, it also seems, surprisingly to me, that I can't even pass internal types to inlined functions using SRTP (statically resolved type parameters).

Consider this:

```
type internal A = { A: int }

let inline f (x: ^a) =
  (^a: (member A: _) x)

let a = { A = 0 }

let x = f a
```

It fails with a compile error on the last `a`:

[image]

Removing `internal` from the definition of `A` fixes the error.

Is this intentional? Is there any way to make this work while keeping `A` internal, apart from copying to an anonymous record (e.g. replacing `a` with `{| a with __ = () |}`)?